# how to customize jQuery image preview code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I am using the following jquery script to preview multiple image before upload and it works good but I can not customize it to match my specifications

```
 <script>

  $(document).ready(function(){

$(function() {
// Multiple images preview in browser
var imagesPreview = function(input, placeToInsertImagePreview) {

    if (input.files) {
        var filesAmount = input.files.length;

        for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(event) {
                $($.parseHTML('<img>')).attr('src', event.target.result).appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
        }
    }

};

$('#product_sub_images').on('change', function() {
    imagesPreview(this, 'div.gallery');
  });
 });
});

</script>
```

I need to make a

- fixed width and height for images for example 200px or show them as thumbs in bootstrap 4
- put images in one row with 10px left and right padding and if there is no enough space for all images in one row they wrap to next row

note :
I am using bootstrap 4 in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of showing them as background images. This allows you to keep them at a consistent height and width. It does crop them, but that is inevitable if you want to display them with a consistant size.

Your code would be:

```
$(function() {
  // Multiple images preview in browser
  var imagesPreview = function(input, placeToInsertImagePreview) {
    if (input.files) {
      var filesAmount = input.files.length;
      for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(event) {
          $($.parseHTML('<div>')).addClass('thumb-c').css('background-image', `url(${event.target.result})`).appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
      }
    }
  };

  $('#product_sub_images').on('change', function() {
    imagesPreview(this, 'div.gallery');
  });
});
```

And here's a testable snippet to show. I made the images 100x100 so you'd see the layout better, but you can change that in the css

```js
let imgs = [
    "https://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
    "https://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
    "https://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
    "https://via.placeholder.com/350x150"
  ],
  placeToInsertImagePreview = $('.gallery');

imgs.forEach(i => $($.parseHTML('<div>')).addClass('thumb-c').css('background-image', `url(${i})`).appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview));
```

```css
.thumb-c {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  float: left;
  margin:0 10px 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class='gallery'>

</div>
```

Comment: i used your css code and addClass function to my pervious code as following and works perfect                 $($.parseHTML('<img>')).addClass('thumb-c').attr('src', event.target.result).appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);

Comment: @MokhtarGhaleb - yes, but it will likely distort any image that isn't at 1x1 ratio. Still, glad it helped

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the FileReader to read them as base64, use [URL.createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) instead

```js
jQuery($ => {
  /**
   * Multiple images preview in browser
   * 
   * @param {HTMLInputElement} input
   * @param {string} placeToInsertImagePreview
   */
  function imagesPreview (input, placeToInsertImagePreview) {
    for (const file of input.files) {
      $('<div>', {
        class: 'thumb-c',
        style: `background-image: url(${URL.createObjectURL(file)})`
      }).appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview)
    }
  }

  $('#product_sub_images').on('change', function() {
    imagesPreview(this, 'div.gallery')
  })
})
```

Comment: what is the different  ??

Comment: Base64 takes up more memory, ObjectURL on the other hand is a direct url pointing to files location. So it can read the binary data directly rather than having to decode it to base64 only to be decoded again to binary and wasting cpu and time. ObjectURL loads faster + requires less code. and you don't need any callbacks

Comment: ahaaaa  I understand your idea thank you very much